# Access an umbraco site from ip

Tags: umbraco

Is it possible to access a page on an umbraco platform only given an ip address? I have an umbraco site that I need to access in an iframe, but the site does not have a domain name. All I have is the IP to the server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible.
Although I wouldn't consider it a pretty solution, here is a quick way to do it.

Note that if the server is using IIS, you may have to remove the binding from the default site first.

I'm assuming your hosting server has a fixed external IP

1. In umbraco, add the current IP as a domain for the umbraco site.(Right-click your base-node and select "Manage Hostnames")
2. Republish all your nodes, that way the site won't rewrite the url to available domains(If that is what you're aiming for, then disregard point 1)
3. Configure the dedicated server to transfer traffic to the umbraco site. (And check firewalls)

And presto, that should do it.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this.